# what is wrong with the query i want to add amount based on debit and credit

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT sum(Case When vld.debit_credit = 'DB' Then amount Else 0 End) as dbtot,
       sum(Case When vld.debit_credit = 'CR' Then amount Else 0 End) as crtot,  
FROM `v_ledger_details`;
```

[image]

what is going wrong i want to sum debit and credit seperate can some one help me.

Comment: Yes seems right to mee too ,, have you error .. ? wrong result ? explain the real problem ù

Comment: Remove the `,` before `from`

Comment: i removed , before from but it still giving error

Comment: What error? Please be more specific than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `,` before `from`, and alias for table `v_ledger_details`, try this;)

```
SELECT sum(Case When vld.`debit_credit` = 'DB' Then amount Else 0 End) as dbtot,
       sum(Case When vld.`debit_credit` = 'CR' Then amount Else 0 End) as crtot 
FROM `v_ledger_details` vld;
```